# How to delete rows in a worksheet based on duplicate values in a single column

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

So I have a workbook with multiple worksheets where I grab the data on a particular sheet(s) depending upon whether a checkbox is checked (in the code below I have 3 check boxes that will grab the data on a particular worksheet depending upon whether it is checked). The data from each worksheet is copied to a sheet that already exists (in this case "Landing Pad") and added to the next empty row. I run the below code when a button is clicked:

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim r As Long
Dim rcnt As Long
Dim Dst As Worksheet


With ThisWorkbook

Set Dst = .Sheets("Landing Pad")
Dst.Cells.ClearContents
Sheets("Landing Pad").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete


'r = 2
rcnt = 1  ' stores amount of inserted rows

If Me.CheckBox1 = True Then
With .Sheets("IT Certification")
r = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
.Range("A1:D" & r).Copy _
Destination:=Dst.Range("A" & rcnt)
rcnt = rcnt + r 'lastrow
End With
End If

If Me.CheckBox2 = True Then
With .Sheets("Business Skills & Productivity")
r = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
.Range("A1:D" & r).Copy _
Destination:=Dst.Range("A" & rcnt)
rcnt = rcnt + r 
End With
End If

If Me.CheckBox3 = True Then
 With .Sheets("Database and Cybersecurity")
r = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
.Range("A1:D" & r).Copy _
Destination:=Dst.Range("A" & rcnt)
rcnt = rcnt + r 
End With
End If

End With

End Sub
```

All the worksheets have the same structure (A:D) but some of them have duplicate values in column D. What I would like to do is have only rows copied depending upon the the values of one particular column (column D) so that there are no duplicate values in that column.

Here's what happens now:

```
Workbook1

A   B   C   D   
aa  ee  ii  zz  
bb  ff  jj  zz
cc  gg  kk  zz
dd  hh  ll  mm

        +

Workbook2

A   B   C   D
nn  pp  rr  tt
oo  qq  ss  uu

        =

New Workbook

A   B   C   D
aa  ee  ii  zz
bb  ff  jj  zz
cc  gg  kk  zz
dd  hh  ll  mm
nn  pp  rr  tt
oo  qq  ss  uu
```

And here's what I'd like to have happen:

```
Workbook1

A   B   C   D   
aa  ee  ii  zz  
bb  ff  jj  zz
cc  gg  kk  zz
dd  hh  ll  mm

        +

Workbook2

A   B   C   D
nn  pp  rr  tt
oo  qq  ss  uu

        =

New Workbook

A   B   C   D
aa  ee  ii  zz
dd  hh  ll  mm
nn  pp  rr  tt
oo  qq  ss  uu
```

I'm not sure on how to go about this...maybe instead of copying each worksheet at a time I could store them in a variable and perhaps use the RemoveDuplicates method to copy the data in the variable once all the data has been added? Or would this require maybe looping through each selected worksheet that has been chosen? Any help appreciated!

Comment: RemoveDuplicates only deletes a cells contents and not the cell's row.

Comment: @dagda13 your post needs few corrections since the Code above shows that you are Coping Data from sheet to another in Workbook. But attached Screen Shot has Captions indicating that you are suppose to works with THREE Workbooks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit 2 -**  First Code Block modified to work with ActiveX Controls in Sheet.

- For a UserForm: Uncomment the comemnted out `If ... Then ' UserForm` and
  delete the following `If` line.

**Edit 1 -**  Details on how to configure the `Const` user settings after the first code block.

**I strongly encourage the use of the second code block.** It removes this error prone kludge and the necessity to modify the code when there are checkbox changes (both the number of checkboxes and the destination sheet name associated with the checkbox).

#### COPY DISTINCT

If the destination should have distinct values in column D, only add rows which meet the condition.

```
Option Explicit

Private Const distinctCol = "D"
Private Const firstCol = "A"
Private Const lastCol = "D"
Private Const destination = "Landing Pad"
Private Const checkboxSource = "CheckBox1, IT Certification; CheckBox2, Business Skills & Productivity; CheckBox3, Database and Cybersecurity"
Private Const separator1 = ", " ' Checkbox Name <separator1> Worksheet Name
Private Const separator2 = "; " ' 1st box&sheet <separator2> 2nd box&sheet

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim r As Long
    Dim distinct As Boolean
    Dim copiedRows As Long
    Dim copyRowCount As Long
    Dim copyRange As Range
    Dim copyDistinct As Range
    Dim Dws As Worksheet, Sws As Worksheet
    Dim checkBoxAndSource As Variant

    Set Dws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(destination)
    Dws.Cells.ClearContents
    Dws.Select
    On Error Resume Next
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0

    copiedRows = 0

    For Each checkBoxAndSource In Split(checkboxSource, separator2)
        'If Me(Split(checkBoxAndSource, separator1)(0)) Then ' UserForm
        If Me.OLEObjects(Split(checkBoxAndSource, separator1)(0)).Object Then
            Set Sws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Split(checkBoxAndSource, separator1)(1))
            Set copyRange = Nothing
            Set copyDistinct = Nothing
            copyRowCount = 0
            For r = 1 To Sws.Range(distinctCol & Sws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                distinct = True
                If copiedRows Then
                    distinct = Dws.Range(distinctCol & 1, distinctCol & _
                        copiedRows).Find(Sws.Cells(r, distinctCol)) Is Nothing
                End If
                If distinct And Not copyDistinct Is Nothing Then
                    distinct = copyDistinct.Find(Sws.Cells(r, distinctCol)) Is Nothing
                End If
                If distinct Then
                    If copyRowCount Then
                        Set copyRange = Union(copyRange, Sws.Range(firstCol & r, lastCol & r))
                        Set copyDistinct = Union(copyDistinct, Sws.Cells(r, distinctCol))
                    Else
                        Set copyRange = Sws.Range(firstCol & r, lastCol & r)
                        Set copyDistinct = Sws.Cells(r, distinctCol)
                    End If
                    copyRowCount = copyRowCount + 1
                End If
            Next r
            If Not copyRange Is Nothing Then
                copyRange.Copy destination:=Dws.Cells(copiedRows + 1, firstCol)
                copiedRows = copiedRows + copyRowCount
            End If
        End If
    Next checkBoxAndSource
End Sub
```

**Edit: `Const` configuration.**

- The three `Const`, *checkboxSource*, *separator1* and *separator2*  work in unison.
- The main `Const` is `checkboxSource`.

  - This is where the checkboxes are associated with their respective sheet names.
  - There can be as few as one and as many as one likes.
- The `Const separator` are only used to delimit the `checkboxSource` string.

  - The comment following them describes what the separator is separating.
  - The separators should include a space after the character if that is
    the way the `checkboxSource` string was formed.
- All three were set according to the original OP code so the OP would not need to change anything.
- The reason for not hard coding the separator values is because both `,` and `;` can be used in a sheet's name (although they should not be).

  - [Seven characters you cant use in worksheet names:](https://www.accountingweb.com/technology/excel/seven-characters-you-cant-use-in-worksheet-names) `\` `/` `*` `[` `]` `:` `?`

#### The whole CheckBox1 → "Sheet Name" is a bit kludgy.

**This implementation uses the Form's Controls Properties instead.**

To complete the implementation of this code, read the instructions for configuring the Form's Controls Properties following this code block.

```
Option Explicit

Private Const distinctCol = "D"
Private Const firstCol = "A"
Private Const lastCol = "D"

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim r As Long
    Dim distinct As Boolean
    Dim copiedRows As Long
    Dim copyRowCount As Long
    Dim copyRange As Range
    Dim copyDistinct As Range
    Dim Dws As Worksheet, Sws As Worksheet
    Dim ctrl As Control

    Set Dws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Me.CommandButton1.Tag)
    Dws.Cells.ClearContents
    Dws.Select
    On Error Resume Next
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0

    copiedRows = 0
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
      If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then
        If ctrl.GroupName = Me.CommandButton1.Tag Then
          If ctrl Then
            Set Sws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ctrl.Tag)
            Set copyRange = Nothing
            Set copyDistinct = Nothing
            copyRowCount = 0
            For r = 1 To Sws.Range(distinctCol & Sws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                distinct = True
                If copiedRows Then
                    distinct = Dws.Range(distinctCol & 1, distinctCol & _
                        copiedRows).Find(Sws.Cells(r, distinctCol)) Is Nothing
                End If
                If distinct And Not copyDistinct Is Nothing Then
                    distinct = copyDistinct.Find(Sws.Cells(r, distinctCol)) Is Nothing
                End If
                If distinct Then
                    If copyRowCount Then
                        Set copyRange = Union(copyRange, Sws.Range(firstCol & r, lastCol & r))
                        Set copyDistinct = Union(copyDistinct, Sws.Cells(r, distinctCol))
                    Else
                        Set copyRange = Sws.Range(firstCol & r, lastCol & r)
                        Set copyDistinct = Sws.Cells(r, distinctCol)
                    End If
                    copyRowCount = copyRowCount + 1
                End If
            Next r
            If Not copyRange Is Nothing Then
                copyRange.Copy destination:=Dws.Cells(copiedRows + 1, firstCol)
                copiedRows = copiedRows + copyRowCount
            End If
          End If
        End If
      End If
    Next ctrl
End Sub
```

**These are the Property Settings for the Form Controls**

- The CommandButton's `Tag` is both:

  - the *Destination Sheet Name* (OP: "Landing Pad") and
  - the CheckBox's `GroupName`
- The CheckBox's `Tag` is its Source Sheet Name (OP: cb1.tag "IT Certification").
- The CheckBox's `GroupName` is its associated CommandButton's `Tag`.
  (See CommanButton's `Tag` above. This is also the Destination Sheet Name.)

  - This convention allows the button to be associated with the checkboxes.
  - It is a guard against the form's other checkboxes being included in the operation.

Comment: Thanks very much, Ted. When I used 'Copy Distinct', I received a Run-time error     '9', Subscript out of range. When I ran the debugger :

 If Me(Split(checkBoxAndSource, separator1)(0)) Then
 
    was highlighted. I'm wondering if I did not asign Private Const separator1 the   correct values, as below:

 Private Const separator1 = "CheckBox1, IT Certification" ' Checkbox Name <separator1> Worksheet Name
 Private Const separator2 = "CheckBox1, IT Certification; CheckBox2, Business Skills & Productivity" ' 1st box&sheet <separator2> 2nd box&sheet

Comment: @dagda13, The code was already configured for you according to your OP. None of the user `Const` needed to be changed. That being said, I have added additional instructions. I encourage you to reread the non code content in the answer. Do understand, the answer code completely replaces your `Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()` code (it is not in addition to, nor do you call it from your code, but rather, it replaces your code and is called by the click of the form's button1). Consider using the second code block instead, change a couple of the form's properties and no more `Const` to deal with.

Comment: Thanks again, still learning on how to access Form Controls Properties. I’m able to access the GroupName field when I right-click on the check boxes but I do not see the Tag property when I right click on CommandButton1. Just want to make sure that these are the fields to be modified or should I modify the code itself, as for example I can see CommandButton1.Tag.

Comment: The second code block uses a Form's Controls' Properties and not a sheet's ActiveX Controls' Properties. There is no `Tag` property for these ActiveX Controls when inserted directly to a sheet. Therefore, use the first code block without modifying the `Const` which already have the proper values as outlined in the OP.

Comment: Gotcha. When I run the first code block I get: 
Run-time error ‘438’:
Object doesn’t support this property or method.
When I use the debugger, line
If Me(Split(checkBoxAndSource, separator1)(0)) Then

Is highlighted.

Comment: @dagda13, My previous comment was misleading as the first code block was also using a Form's Controls and not the ActiveX Controls in the sheet. I modified one line and now the first code block works with ActiveX Controls in the sheet rather than a UserForm. You can copy/paste the first code block again or just replace the line referenced in your comment with the modified line in the first code block.

Comment: Success! Thanks so much for all the help and for being so patient. This is perfect. I’m assuming if I want to add more check boxes/corresponding tabs, just add them to checkboxSource. Thanks again.

Comment: That is correct and also why I pulled those from the code and made them a user defined Const, so they can be modified or added to or removed.

Answer (score 0):

This little code should do it for you.
 See "Sub Test" how to call "delDoubleRow".

```
Private Sub delDoubleRow(aSht As Worksheet, aCol As String)
Dim rx As Long
Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = aSht.Range(aCol & aSht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For rx = lastrow To 1 Step -1  'count backwards from last to keep next row(rx) valid!
  If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(aSht.Range(aCol & "1" & ":" & aCol & rx), aSht.Range(aCol & rx)) > 1 Then
    aSht.Rows(rx).EntireRow.Delete
  End If
Next
End Sub

Public Sub Test()
delDoubleRow ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Landing Pad"), "D"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, again! Unfortunately the code does not appear to work. I may not be incorporating it properly into the code I have above.

Comment: Do you have further information like messages or so, or don't you know how sub-/function-calls are used ?

Comment: No messages, and no. Still new to VBA, and lots still to learn obviously...but this has been very educational. :)

Answer (score -1):

*I would like to suggest this VBA code (Macro), will help you to Delete entire Row/Rows based on Duplicate Values in Column D.*

```
Sub RemoveDuplicatesCells_EntireRow()


Dim rng As Range
Dim x As Integer

Sheets("LandingPad").Activate 
Set rng = Sheets("LandingPad").Range("A:D")
Range("A:D").Select


  Application.ScreenUpdating = False


  On Error GoTo InvalidSelection
  Set rng = Selection
  On Error GoTo 0


  On Error GoTo InputCancel
    x = InputBox("Which Column Should Look For Duplicates? (Number only!)", _
      "Select A Column", 1)
  On Error GoTo 0


  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


  rng.EntireRow.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=x

  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

  With ActiveSheet
    .EnableSelection = xlNoSelection
  End With

 Application.CutCopyMode = False


Exit Sub


InvalidSelection:
  MsgBox "You selection is not valid", vbInformation
  Exit Sub

InputCancel:

End Sub
```

**How it works:**

- **Copy** & **Paste** this code with **Landing Pad Sheet** as **Standard Module**.
- Activate this MACRO using `Call  RemoveDuplicatesCells_EntireRow` statement just before the last `End With` in the Code you are using to Copy  Data From different Sheets to `Landing Pad Sheet`.
- Use this command line to call the MACRO.

`Call LandingPad.RemoveDuplicatesCells_EntireRow`

- Respond **INPUT BOX** with the appropriate *Column Number*, in your case is `4` for `D`.

Comment: Thanks Rajesh! 
I copied and pasted Sub RemoveDuplicatesCells_EntireRow() below the code that Im using, and called it before the last End With.
I receive the following error when I click the button:
Run-time error ‘1004’
Select method of Range class failed
When I run the debugger the following line in Sub RemoveDuplicatesCells_EntireRow() is highlighted:
Range("A:D").Select
My destination worksheet (Sheet14 (Landing Pad)) is in the Microsoft Excel Objects…I’m not sure if I’m setting it correctly as a standard module and maybe this is the problem? Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: @dagda13, as far my Code is concern is working without any error, I've tested it many times before post as Answer here. Let me check one more time.

Comment: @dagda13, check my post I've edited Line no 4, 5 & 6 to activate the Sheet `LANDINGPAD` to delete the duplicate Rows. Also,, while test your code I got lots of error `Invalid use of properties & Methods`,, for WITH  This Workbook then next WITH also !!

Comment: @dagda13 use this command line to activate Macro `Call LandingPad.RemoveDuplicatesCells_EntireRow`. **Since the Macro is stored with Sheet LandingPad** Check the **How it works** section with my post there also I've edited.